# How to exclude the aspect in JUnit

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-aop, powermockito, aspect

I have to unit test the method submitApplication which is inside Processor class.

@PreValidate(actionName="PRE_VALIDATE") on method submitApplication is associated with Aspect(PreValidateAspect), which is called
automatically as i do test the method. I do not want this Aspect being called, since i would like to test the lines only which inside the function.

Used Versions: Spring version(4.3.16), mockito-core (2.8.47), powermock-api-mockito (2-1.7.0)

Please let me know how to disable/exculde this aspect code run as i unit test the function.

```
 public class ProcessorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Processor processor;


    @Test
    public void testSubmitApplication() {
        processor.submitApplication();
    }
}



public class Processor {

    @PreValidate(actionName="PRE_VALIDATE")
    public void submitApplication(){
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}


@Aspect
@Component
@Configurable
public class PreValidateAspect {
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && " +
            "(@annotation(com.PreValidate) " +
            "|| @within(com.PreValidate) )")
    public Object validate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is use [@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) with [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ProcessorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Processor processor;


    @Test
    public void testSubmitApplication() {
        processor.submitApplication();
    }
}



public class Processor {

    @PreValidate(actionName="PRE_VALIDATE")
    public void submitApplication(){
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}


@Aspect
@Component
@Configurable
@Profile("!test")
public class PreValidateAspect {
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && " +
            "(@annotation(com.PreValidate) " +
            "|| @within(com.PreValidate) )")
    public Object validate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to modify PreValidateAspect.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go as suggested by [coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8030619/coder).

However this approach didn't work for me. As mentioned in the comment. The aspect cannot be mocked. Instead you can do this.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Configurable
public class PreValidateAspect {

    @Autowired
    Utils utils;

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && " +
            "(@annotation(com.PreValidate) " +
            "|| @within(com.PreValidate) )")
    public Object validate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
           if(utils.aspectUtil()) {
              return joinPoint.proceed();
           }
           //else statement
    }

}

public class Utils{
    public Object aspectUtil() {
       //your business logic here
       if(validate()){
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
}



public class ProcessorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Processor processor;

    @MockBean
    Utils utils;

    @Test
    public void testSubmitApplication() {
        when(utils.validateUtil()).thenReturn(true);
        processor.submitApplication();
    }
}
```

By this move your business logic from aspect to a class and mock the class instead to return true;

Comment: Since validate method has ProceedingJoinPoint as argument.   when(prevalidateAspect.validate()).thenReturn(joinPoint.proceed());  This line is not compiling.  So I used  when(prevalidateAspect.validate(any(ProceedingJoinPoint.class))).thenReturn(joinPoint.proceed()) ,  i am getting this error Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Comment: when(prevalidateAspect.validate(joinPoint)).thenReturn(joinPoint.proceed());   throws NullPointerExcecption

Comment: Reason of NullPointerException is , it is not  by Spring Boot Test, we can't use @MockBean

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check whether this helps

Comment: i am not allowed to modify PreValidateAspect

Comment: then you need to mock the method that's being called in the aspect so that the aspect returns joinPoint.proceed().